# Rails, insert span tag in form_for label custom text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

My problem is I wanted to insert a `<span>` tag in `form_for label` custom text. In normal html code, it would be like this:

`<label>Address<span class="required">*</span></label>`

but it Rails, how would I insert it in here:

`<%= f.label :address, "Address" %>`

It's just an indication for required fields.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As most of the Form helpers, you can pass a do/block instead of the name argument:

```
<%= f.label :address do %>
  Address<span class="required">*</span>
<% end %>
```

Works with `link_to` also:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div>Hey!</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer is neat. I almost end up with `content_tag`, almost lost :)

Answer (score 7):

You can just do like this

```
<%= f.label :address, "Address<span class='required'>*</span>".html_safe %>
```

This produces the following `HTML`

```
<label for="address">Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
```

**OR**

You can do like this too.

```
<%= f.label :address do %>
   Address<span class="required">*</span>
<% end %>
```