# Insert glyphicon inside rails form_for text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, glyphicons

I've been trying to find a way to insert a `glyphicon` into a `text_field` for a rails `form_for`. Here is how I have the form setup in rails:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => "form-control input-sm", :name => "first_name", placeholder: "First Name" %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

So obviously this will treat the `f.text_field` and the `i` tags as separate elements. So the `i` will be placed below the `f.text_field(input)` and not in it. The question therefore stands, is there a way in rails to place an `i` or `span` tag of some sort, inside the `f.text_field`? I know that I can `position: relative` the `i` element and place it appropriately on top of the `input` field that is created by the `f.text_field`.

Any answers or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a block to make this. Try something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => "form-control input-sm", :name => "first_name", placeholder: "First Name" do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This kind of block syntax works for other helpers too like link_to, button_to, etc.

Comment: I tried to place the `text_field` into a block but nothing happens. When I inspect the element, it renders the page as if that `i` doesn't even exist. Am I doing something wrong? My syntax is literally copy+paste with what you have put down.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Looks like I messed up my answer previously. Hope this helps.

You can convert the field to a do block like so:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name do %>
  :name => "first_name",
  :placeholder => "First Name",
  :class => "form-control input-sm",
  :html => "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign></i>"
<% end %>
```

I think the answer to this question provides good detail:

[Rails, insert span tag in form_for label custom text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937695/rails-insert-span-tag-in-form-for-label-custom-text)